# Drawing a ForceDirected graph with JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit

Tags: javascript, graph, infovis

I have two tables in database like this:

```
Table_1
PK Column generated by db...
Any other columns...

Table_1_association
PK Column generated by db...
FK Column for Table_1
Another FK Column for Table_1
```

In this case, I can have the follow lines in `Table_1_association`

```
FK1 -> FK2

1 -> 2
1 -> 3
1 -> 4
1 -> 5
1 -> 6
1 -> 7
7 -> 8
7 -> 9
10 -> 1
10 -> 7
10 -> 11
10 -> 12
```

I can have

```
9 -> 1
```

too.

I'd like to make a graph that show this structure.
I used FOrceDirected graph with 'arrow' Edges because the direction is
`FK1` to `FK2` (the `->` in example above).

But I can't get. Some arrows are in wrong direction.

Does the ForceDirected graph allow this?

Comment: I've been having the same problem... it seems that the direction of the arrow is dependent on the order in the list of adjacencies in the json list. I implemented a custom arrow that "should" draw it backwards and that seems to be working, though it is hardly a permenant solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify direction by adding `$direction` to the data section in the JSON which is a list of two strings representing the "from" node ID and the "to" node ID, respectively.  For example:

```
"adjacencies" : [
   {
      "nodeTo" : "222",
      "data" : {
         "$direction" : [
            "111",
            "222"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```